# Use space-around without setting height value

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to put 3 texts on the screen one on the top, one on the middle an one on the bottom. For this I thought about using the `space-around` property. This is my code

```
        <Screen style={styles.container} backgroundColor={color.transparent}>
           <View style={styles.playerContainer}>
               <View><Text>text 1</Text></View>
               <View><Text>text 2</Text></View>
               <View><Text>text 3</Text></View>
           </View>
       </Screen>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },
  playerContainer:{
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
});
```

This is not working as expected. It looks better is I set a height for playerContainer, but I am enable to calculate the right hight because of the navigation bar etc.. I just need to add three text in the container. I must calculate the hight of playerContainer or I am doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first entry to be at the start of the container, the second to be at the center, and the last to be at the end, you need `justifyContent: 'space-between'`.  I found this article helpful when learning about flex in React Native https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/understanding-flex-in-react-native-b34dfb4b16d1

Comment: I updated the post with a screenshot. The blog post is great but does not solve my problem

Comment: I'm not clear on the desired behavior, can you add a screenshot or say more about what you want?

Comment: The red view should have the height of the hole screen.

Comment: add `flex: 1` to the `playerContainer` style

Comment: It was all inside a ScrollView. I had to remove the ScrollView and add flex:1 for this to work